# Cannot delete Profile pictures album from Facebook, only has a single picture inside

Tags: facebook, photos

I can't delete a photo album from my Facebook profile. This album contains only one picture and the name of the album is **Profile pictures**.

I tried several ways to delete it as I changed the viewing mode from public to "only me" but the option "Edit Album" doesn't appear. I have deleted other albums except this one.

Does the name "Profile pictures" make it a persistent undeletable object? I also can’t seem to rename it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can’t delete that particular album. Even if is empty, the album is still present, being automatically generated by Facebook.

To delete a picture from this album, go to the album → open the respective picture → click on *Options* at the bottom of the picture → click *Delete This Photo*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 

My objective is to delete the picture that is into it. I changed/removed my profile picture several times but still the album contains one particular picture that was my old profile picture. 

If this is a feature of the facebook to keep one album for its own use then, how it allows me to create another album with the same name and that can be deleted too. 

Any help?

Regards

Comment: It’s a "system" album if you want and even if you create another album with the same name, it’s not the same thing. You can delete every picture that’s inside this particular album.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and fantastic help. I have done it. I had clicked more than thousand times to achieve this.Further I would like to say that all the help scattered in various webpages such as yahoo answer is also not correct. Facebook itself has no such topic which can be found out easily. I'm really grateful to you for your help. Thank you very much. :))